# Using Powers in Pascal

Tags: freepascal

```
program Project1;

var
  num1: integer;
  num2: integer;
  answer: integer;
begin
  writeln('This program will accept two input values and raise the first number to the power of the second value');
  writeln('Please enter the first number');
  readln(num1);
  writeln('Please enter the second number');
  readln(num2);

  writeln(num1**num2);
end.
```

This is my code in Pascal. I want to enter two values and answer will return the first value of the power to the second. Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin already said it:  "Can anyone help" doesn't tell us with what. Rather properly state the problem: **what do you expect to happen and what happens *actually***? Do you get an error message and if so, what is it? Add this and other relevant information to the question (you can edit your own question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [power operator `**` for numeric types](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse102.html#x211-23300015.4) is not defined for numeric types. However, it is a recognised operator and the `math` unit defines overloads for integer and floating point types. So you must use that unit and then your code compiles and runs correctly.

Add

```
uses
  math;
```

to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a `for` loop:

```
pow:=1;
for i:=1 to num2 do
 pow:=pow*num1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think this function will be help you.

```
Program Power_fun;
    {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
    Function Power(x, p: Double): Double;
      Var negative: Double;
    Begin
        If(x<0) Then
        Begin
          If(Round(p) mod 2 = 0) Then negative := 1
            Else negative := -1;
          x := -x;
        End
        Else negative := 1;
        Power := Exp(p*(Ln(x)))*negative;
    End;
Begin
    Writeln(Power(2, 2));
    Writeln(Power(5, 2));
    Writeln(Power(-2, 2));
    Writeln(Power(-2, 3));
    Writeln(Power(-5, 3));
    readln;
End.
```